# How can I move the center point of the background image down?

Tags: css

I have a background image (a schematic) spinning.  But I need the center of that image to be lower.

If you think of it like a spinning disc, we should only see the top of the disc, and not the bottom.

I need it to stay within the same border/frame area.
I need the 'product images' to stay centered where they are.

You can see what I have here:

http://www.meteorsite.com/images/spinner/

Thanks in advance for any suggestions...

```js
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
    
    setInterval(function() {
      $('#slideshow > div:first')
        .fadeOut(3000).next().fadeIn(3000).end()
        .appendTo('#slideshow');console.log($('#slideshow > div:first').height()+'-'+$('#slideshow > div:first').width())
    }, 5000);
```

```css
  *{margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box}
    
        #slideshow {
      
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 50;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        }
        #slideshow > div {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        }
    
        .wrapper {
         width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        animation: bend 1s linear 0s alternate;  /*linear XS is delay before disc 
       flaps down*/
       -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
       }
    
      .vinyl {
      
       width: 600px;
       height: 600px;
       border-radius: 50%;
       animation: moveLeft 0s linear 0s alternate, spin 30s linear 0s infinite; /* 
       time to spin, etc */
       }
        .vinyl div {
        border: 0px solid #222;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 5px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        }
       .vinyl__label {
        border: none;
        background: white;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        background-image: url(schemo.gif);
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        }
      
    @keyframes spin {
      0% {
        transform: rotateZ(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
      }
      25% {
        transform: rotateZ(90deg) rotateY(0deg);
      }
      75% {
        transform: rotateZ(270deg) rotateY(0deg);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotateZ(360deg) rotateY(0deg);
      }
    }
    @keyframes bend {    /* how far the disc leans back*/
      from {
        transform: rotateX(55deg);
     
      }
      to {
        transform: rotateX(55deg);
      }
    }
    
    
    @keyframes moveLeft {
      transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
      -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
      /** Chrome & Safari **/
      -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
      /** Firefox **/
      -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
      /** Opera **/
      from {
        transform: translate(350px, 0);
      }
      to {
        transform: translate(350px, 0);
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position: absolute;left: 0;right: 0;margin: auto">
    <div class="wrapper" style="position: relative;"> 
     <div style="box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);">   
       <div class="vinyl">    
      <div class="vinyl__label">
        <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>    
       </div>
     </div> 
    </div>
    <div id="slideshow" style="position: absolute;">
      
    <div style="background: url(&quot;http://web3designs.com/spin/slide-1.gif&quot;) center center no-repeat;"></div><div style="background: url(&quot;http://web3designs.com/spin/slide-2.gif&quot;) center center no-repeat; display: none;"></div><div style="background: url(&quot;http://web3designs.com/spin/slide-3.gif&quot;) center center no-repeat; display: none;"></div></div>
    </div>
```

Here is a quick draft of the disc's position:
[image]

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Totally valid, j08691 - thank you for correcting me on that.  I've updated the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `perspective` to your `.wrapper` to make it true 3D.

Then rotate  `.vinyl` around `X` axis to set a view angle and spin, spin, spin around `Z` axis:

```js
$(() => {
  $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

  setInterval(function() {
    $('#slideshow > div:first')
      .fadeOut(3000).next().fadeIn(3000).end()
      .appendTo('#slideshow');
   //console.log($('#slideshow > div:first').height() + '-' + $('#slideshow > div:first').width())
  }, 5000);
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

#slideshow {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 50;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#slideshow>div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  animation: bend 1s linear 0s alternate;
  /*linear XS is delay before disc 
   flaps down*/
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  perspective:1000px;
}

.wrapper > div {overflow:hidden; box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);}

.vinyl {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  border-radius: 50%; border:solid 1px;
  transform: translateY(50%) rotateX(60deg) rotateZ(0);
  animation: moveLeft 0s linear 0s alternate, spin 30s linear 0s infinite;
  /* 
   time to spin, etc */
}

.vinyl div {
  border: 0px solid #222;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.vinyl__label {
  border: none;
  background: white;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url(https://etap.com/images/default-source/product/electrical-single-line-diagram/electrical-single-line-diagram-53a2be6450c286c028629ff00005ae238.jpg?sfvrsn=14);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    transform: translateY(50%) rotateX(60deg) rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes bend {
  /* how far the disc leans back*/
  from {
    transform: rotateX(55deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateX(55deg);
  }
}

@keyframes moveLeft {
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  /** Chrome & Safari **/
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  /** Firefox **/
  -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  /** Opera **/
  from {
    transform: translate(350px, 0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(350px, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div style="position: absolute;left: 0;right: 0;margin: auto">
  <div class="wrapper" style="position: relative;">
    <div>
      <div class="vinyl">
        <div class="vinyl__label">
          <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="slideshow" style="position: absolute">
    <div style="background: url(http://web3designs.com/spin/slide-1.gif) center center no-repeat;"></div>
    <div style="background: url(http://web3designs.com/spin/slide-2.gif) center center no-repeat; display: none;"></div>
    <div style="background: url(http://web3designs.com/spin/slide-3.gif) center center no-repeat; display: none;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Kosh Very and thanks a lot for helping on this.  I still have two remaining questions:  1) How do I move the center of the disc downwards, so that we only see the top part of the disc.   2)  How do i keep the disc within the frame (so the sides of the disc don't pop out of the border)?

Comment: @BlueDaNoob, there is no disc, there is a rectangle. So I do not understand what you mean clearly. Could you please elaborate on the expected result? Please draw a picture and add it to your post.

Comment: Hi Kosh Very, I added an image that will hopefully show what I mean. The 'center point' of the rectangle (spinning part) should be at the bottom of the viewing area, so only the top part of the spinning image should show.

Comment: @BlueDaNoob, so you do not need it spinning in 3d, right?

Comment: Yes, i need it to spin in 3D as it does, i just need to move the entire thing down so that only the top of it shows in the frame.

Comment: Amazing, thank you Kosh Very!!!   Just one last question - what variable is it I can change to move the 'spinning image' vertically on the screen, if i need to?  Thank you!

Comment: Also - the spinning image seems to 'jump' up when you first run it.  Can I remove that?

Comment: @BlueDaNoob, as you see in the code, we used CSS `transform` property to rotate and move objects. So I'd suggest read on it e.g. on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transforms). This knowledge would save your time. Regarding the 'jump', I do not see it here. Probably it's another question. Cheers!